# Identify user who started a daemon as root and absolute path of configuration

Tags: linux

Want to know (using any linux tool/cmd), who actually started a process using sudo, on linux and using a configuration file from his home directory? How to check who started it and what's the absolute path of this configuration file? I have looked into /proc/$PID/environ and found the user but can't seem to find, the absolute path of the config file? This user has same dir/conf.prod in multiple sub directories?

Comment: "using sudo ... and using a configuration file from his home dir" - do you mean a sudo command that reads a configuration ? Started a daemon or ran sudo or both?

Comment: @suspectus He started a server and config file is for server's use. sudo is used to start the process as root. hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the system log first. This will be in `/var/log`. Depending on what platform, it will called `messages` or  `auth.log` or `system.log`.

example in system log of sudo command logging-:

```
Apr 19 23:22:14 diabolus.local sudo[1583]:    suspectu : TTY=ttys001 ; PWD=/home/suspectu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/date
```

Regarding the configuration used to start a service, look at the service's logs. Alternatively `lsof` can be used to display thefiles (which may include config files) a process has open.

`lsof -p <pid>`